# New to external css; tables for side by side presentation

Tags: css, css-tables

I'm at beginner level CSS but a friend started a CSS in HTML4 or 5?  So I have a steep learning curve.  And I'm a bit lost.

I have personal websites written in HTML that I'm converting to CSS. e.g. I don't require perfection, just something easy that works.

I have hundreds of pages with single row, 2 cell tables... and 4 to 6 of these single tables per page. The left holds a newspaper clipping; the right holds the transcribed text. The images vary in `length` and `width`; the images are organized by surname (so I cannot group them by image sizes). In between the single HTML tables, I have a centered asterick * to separate the tables. It's simple, looks clean and orderly.

I'm looking for a very basic and easy to understand write up for table to add to the CSS file that will keep the left (image) cell a set `width`, so every vertical line of the tables 'lines up' regardless of the image size or whether the image fills the cell or not.

What would be best here? A `.table` that I reuse on the same page, so it's similar to what I have now in HTML?

Or a new `#tablename` and use `colspan` on every other table row for the * symbol?

If I take one of the `#tablenumber` that I already have, do I just change the name, like use `#news` then list the details for `td`/`tr` etc?  Could someone give an example please?

Could someone give an example of how to write a `.table` for a CSS file to show me how to set it up that way?

Comment: Every community has its rules which participants  should follow. The tab table clearly states "Do not use". There is no generic "table" as it could means a database table a table in word or PDF, a data structure and  so on. This is being resolved. Your contributions are owned by Stack Exchange and are not personal to you and will get edited by the community or removed. Your post was not edited because it was a beginners and your demand that your post should not be edited is not within the guidelines of Stack Exchange- However you contributions are welcomed and your participation helpful;thanks

Answer (score 1):

Layouts that use html tables to keep things in place are long gone dead and its considered a bad design approach for several valid reasons.

I would recommend you to get yourself familirased with the basics of CSS, and try designing things from scratch in CSS. Here's why, not only will it be less painful then manually converting table layouts to CSS, it would also add some future proofing and better device support for your website, specially if you plan on going the responsice design way.

If you're not ready to do full fledged course on CSS I would highly recommend you to try out

**[Bootstrap Framework (by Twitter)](http://getbootstrap.com/)**

**[Foundation Framework (by ZURB)](http://foundation.zurb.com/)** (my personal favourite)

they are very easy way to quickly protoype a website without extensive knowledge of CSS/Js, and incorporate the best programming practices from the world of web design, so you don't have much to bother ;)

Also it would be helpful if you posted a link / screenshot along with your question. Otherwise its hard for us to make out what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I would still like examples of how to write the items in external CSS for table, both as .table and #table.

Answer (score 0):

While I do wholeheartedly agree with Shubham that tables should not be used for layout, it can sometimes happen that you have to maintain an older website that you're not going to completely rewrite, or it happens that you'll have to make a newsletter where tables still seem to work best.

Since you didn't include a sample, I'll assume it would look something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis magna arcu, maximus a odio sit amet, semper viverra augue. Donec velit felis, tempor eu aliquet vestibulum, pulvinar ac metus. Sed eu neque eu tortor placerat vulputate. Mauris tristique ipsum ac suscipit ultricies. Nullam dapibus pellentesque neque. Cras vulputate fringilla lorem, sit amet bibendum ipsum. Phasellus dignissim, leo ac imperdiet sagittis, dui justo sollicitudin risus, a pellentesque risus quam vel purus. Pellentesque nisl odio, lobortis ut felis sed, commodo molestie eros. Donec malesuada, libero in pharetra facilisis, massa massa sagittis justo, id luctus leo nibh at enim.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<center>*</center>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis magna arcu, maximus a odio sit amet, semper viverra augue. Donec velit felis, tempor eu aliquet vestibulum, pulvinar ac metus. Sed eu neque eu tortor placerat vulputate. Mauris tristique ipsum ac suscipit ultricies. Nullam dapibus pellentesque neque. Cras vulputate fringilla lorem, sit amet bibendum ipsum. Phasellus dignissim, leo ac imperdiet sagittis, dui justo sollicitudin risus, a pellentesque risus quam vel purus. Pellentesque nisl odio, lobortis ut felis sed, commodo molestie eros. Donec malesuada, libero in pharetra facilisis, massa massa sagittis justo, id luctus leo nibh at enim.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<center>*</center>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x400" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis magna arcu, maximus a odio sit amet, semper viverra augue. Donec velit felis, tempor eu aliquet vestibulum, pulvinar ac metus. Sed eu neque eu tortor placerat vulputate. Mauris tristique ipsum ac suscipit ultricies. Nullam dapibus pellentesque neque. Cras vulputate fringilla lorem, sit amet bibendum ipsum. Phasellus dignissim, leo ac imperdiet sagittis, dui justo sollicitudin risus, a pellentesque risus quam vel purus. Pellentesque nisl odio, lobortis ut felis sed, commodo molestie eros. Donec malesuada, libero in pharetra facilisis, massa massa sagittis justo, id luctus leo nibh at enim.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Working example at: https://jsfiddle.net/7dsgpokL/

For the css, its best to use `.table` (class selector) but preferably with a more descriptive name. This way you'll only have to write the css once, its easier to maintain, and clearer to read. You can also just use the element selector `table`, but you might have more tables on the page, so I'll use the class selector instead.

This rules out the `#table` (id selector) because you can only have one element with the same `id` on one page. You'd be stuck thinking of names like `#clipping1`, `#clipping2`, etc. Which makes your css a mess.

Now, managing html tables with css is a bit tricky, since they do what they're designed to do: expand if they data requires it. So even if you gave the `td` with the image a fixed width, they will expand if you insert a wider image. To prevent this, you can give the images a `max-width` (maximum width) of the same width you gave the td.

The css would only need to be something as simple as setting the width of the first td in the table to a fixed width, and the image inside that to have a `max-width` of the same. In this case I named the css class 'news-clipping':

```
.news-clipping tr td:first-child {
  width: 100px;
}

.news-clipping tr td:first-child img {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

You'd only have to add the `class="news-clipping"` to the tables that you want aligned.

```
<table class="news-clipping">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<center>*</center>
<table class="news-clipping">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example at https://jsfiddle.net/7dsgpokL/2/